# Spartacus NavigationUIComponent - cx-navigation-ui cx-icon disappears on and o

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

**Dropdown icon disappears on and off after clicking on view order history. I am thinking the issue could be from cx-navigation-ui (out-of-the-box code).**

```
<cx-navigation-ui
  [ngClass]="(styleClass$ | async) ?? ''"
  [node]="node$ | async" [flyout]="false"
>
</cx-navigation-ui>
```

[step 1 - 3 indicates the behavior when I click on the drop icon it opens fine, but after clicking on the check order history drop-down disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC3i9.png)

**Expect the dropdown icon to not disappear after several clicks.**